Unable to re-use an old deleted Apple Account (aka Apple ID)
I deleted an old Apple Account (aka Apple ID), which was an email address that I still have.  Now I'd like to add this email to my current Apple Account, but I am still getting the same error: "This email address is not available".
Does anyone know whether this is just a matter of time so I may plan on using it again in a week, month, year.... or never?

From https://support.apple.com/en-us/102559

Can I use the primary email address for my deleted Apple Account to create a new Apple Account or with another existing Apple Account?


No, once your Apple Account is deleted, you can’t use the email address that you used with it to create a new Apple Account for as long as Apple retains the one-way hash of the email address. For third-party (non-Apple) domain accounts, the one-way hash is deleted after six years. For other accounts, this is retained according to Apple's retention policy, which is reviewed regularly. In addition, you can’t use that email address with another existing Apple Account except as a rescue email. Also, if your primary Apple Account email address is with a Custom Email Domain, it can never be reused to create an Apple Account after your Apple Account is deleted, even if the domain ownership changes.


My email's still unusable, and it's been close to 15 years, so I'd say it's effectively not possible.

I agree @barbecue never expect to prove you owned the old email if you delete your account or add an email as an adjunct to another Apple account.

You might try plus addressing.
So, let's say the email address in question is gidiav@gmail.com.
You can use the email address gidiav+apple@gmail.com; emails to that address will arrive in the inbox of gidiav@gmail.com.
I have no idea if this will work; Apple might have coded things to prevent you doing this. But it's worth a try.

Yes, it works!   Thanks!

Rock and roll! Glad to have helped! @gidiav
